# Windows 8.1 update search never ends

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, drivers, troubleshooting

### Disclaimer

This question has been asked so many times already, but none of the solutions worked, so here we go again.

### Introduction

A friend of mine had a problem with her Laptop. So I re-installed Windows 8.1 and wanted to search for updates, but it never found updates. At first I thought it was just taking long too load and said to her she should do this again when she's home.

A few days later she sends me a message that she can't connect her TV via HDMI (the Laptop never sees the other display, not even in the settings) and that also all her functional keys (brightness, etc.) don't work. I asked her to show me dxdiag (because I wanted to see if she can install drivers if it's an Nvidia gpu for example) and saw that she had sth. along "microsoft basic display adapter", which I found out will be displayed if no drivers are installed. So I wanted to do the update search again, however, like before it never finds updates (not even after hours)

### Research

So I started researching a bit and see this is a really common problem. I have now tested so many things out, I don't know what else to do. I did

- Run the Windows Update Troubleshooter, which found problems and sait it fixed them. The error code was/is `0x80070490`
- Tried to install [this (3173424)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3173424) and [this(3172614)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3172614) driver manually, however then it's always stuck at sth. along the lines (it's in German, so only rough translation) `Windows Update standalone installer for updats on this computer` and like before, never ends
- Tried to install [this(3138615)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/3138615) driver, same result as above
- Do the listed steps found in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1166502/276561) and [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1259752/276561)
- Do the listed steps found in [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/247380/how-to-fix-windows-update-when-it-gets-stuck/)
- Tried to use autopatcher -> No result
- Tried to use portableupdate -> No result

I was also able to copy the contents of her log to my computer (I'm doing all these steps via TeamViewer) which you can [find here (care, big file)](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/2zvT-57X5GdBfb9FZNhsoA)

The last thing I would try to do is to re-install Windows 8.1 again or just go straight to Windows 10, however we don't live THAT close together and she and I work a lot so it will be hard to find a date. So the preferred solution would be that I can somehow fix it via Teamviewer. I'm nearly giving up, but maybe you have some ideas?

Comment: This [article](https://appuals.com/windows-update-error-0x80070490/) contains some more stuff that you may not have tried. The [System Update Readiness tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/947821/fix-windows-update-errors-by-using-the-dism-or-system-update-readiness) may also help. Please add a report about them inside your post.

Comment: Hey, I'll have a look into the first article. The second one I already foudn and didn't help. The same link was in one of the linked superuser.com answers. I'll try the first article  next time I can

Comment: In Services, check if the service `BranchCache` is set to Manual. If nothing helps, you might not escape [Repair Install Windows 8](https://www.eightforums.com/threads/repair-install-windows-8.26095/) for an In-place upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to fix similar issues using https://www.wsusoffline.net in the past. An outdated windows update agent was unable to correctly communicate with the update servers. Wsusoffline was able to install the required updates fixing the windows update agent communication issues. No guarantees it will help in your case but definetly worth a try.

Comment: Trying that out right now! So far, it downloads updates! Will keep you posted

Comment: Windows had to be restarted and was showing that updates need to be installed. So far it looks really good. We're just installing the remaining updates!

Comment: Bad news. After the second iteration she restarted her laptop, but Windows only showed a note (it's in German, so I'll try to roughly translate): "Setting up of updates could not be completed. Changes are being reversed. Do not turn off your computer" I asked her for an update, hope she can answer me soon.

Comment: Oh, that's rather unfortunate. The most recent restore point will be restored and windows should start without issue. You'll probably end up in an update/restore loop when you try to update again though.

Comment: Yep... Really sad :( Seems like I have to go the route with reinstalling again.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before with the current laptop I am using (mind you it's Windows 10) but I think the same rules still apply. It is not an easy answer, but it did work for me. The Windows Update was hanging and the troubleshooter claimed to fix it, but I knew that it had not. Several reboots and tries of the troubleshooter later and it had finally worked.

It may not be the answer you're looking for, but it may just be one of those tedious things that are the pain in the ass to fix. I would also recommend having a wired connection to the laptop to speed up the download and installation wait. My laptop hadn't been touched in years and had a litany of updates and it was an arduous process to say the least. It was a rinse and repeat procedure for me to fix my laptop (that did take several hours). Don't give up and don't lose hope on it! Again, may not be the answer you wanted, but it is what worked for me.